# Separating continuum in the disc

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, plane-curves, continuum-theory

Continuum = compact connected set.

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are nonempty disjoint open subsets of $[0,1]^2$. Is there necessarily a continuum $K\subseteq [0,1]^2$ that divides $U$ and $V$? More precisely, is there a continuum $K$ such that $[0,1]^2\setminus K$ is the union of two disjoint open sets $T$ and $W$ with $U\subseteq T$ and $V\subseteq W$.

It seems like this is a classical result but I don't know.

Note: You may not be able to choose $K$ to be an arc because for certain open $U$ and $V$ it could have to be something like the topolgist's sine curve.

Comment: What do you mean with "continuum"? A set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: But why is $[0,1]^2\setminus (U\cup V)$ connected?

Comment: You should define continuum here.

Comment: @ForeverMozart It is not connected in general.

Comment: @Del right, I see because $U$ and $V$ could be like tubes.

Comment: @ForeverMozart I assume you mean annuli, then yes, that could be an example. If you require $U$ and $V$ to be connected maybe you can obtain a connected $K$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: True for connected U, V.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Do you have a quick proof in mind?

Comment: @Del: First, let $A$ be a component of $R^2-cl(V)$; then $A$ contains $U$, is connected and has connected complement. Then $\partial A$ will be the required separation. (An argument for this is needed, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, consider these two sets:
$$U = \{ x \in [-1,1]^2: |x| \in (1/8, 1/7) \cup (1/4, 1/3) \}$$
$$V = \{ x \in [-1,1]^2: |x| \in (1/10, 1/9) \cup (1/6, 1/5) \}$$
where $|\cdot |$ denotes the usual Euclidean norm.

Comment: ok I see.  I was hoping it was true...